# Cannot access services exposed on internal load balancer with nginx ingress

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-elb, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster with only private subnets, So i tried to expose a service on internal load balancer by adding this annotation to the nginx ingress controller service:

**service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"**

the porblem is that i cannot access the hostname (kibana.com) defined in the ingress resource (with vpn)

here is my code :

nginx ingress controller :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress 
  namespace: nginx-ingress

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: default-server-secret
  namespace: nginx-ingress
type: Opaque
data:
  tls.crt: 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
  tls.key: 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

---

kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
  namespace: nginx-ingress
data:
  proxy-protocol: "True"
  real-ip-header: "proxy_protocol"
  set-real-ip-from: "0.0.0.0/0"

---

kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - services
  - endpoints
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - secrets
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
  - update
  - create
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - events
  verbs:
  - create
  - patch
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  - networking.k8s.io
  resources:
  - ingresses
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - "extensions"
  resources:
  - ingresses/status
  verbs:
  - update
- apiGroups:
  - k8s.nginx.org
  resources:
  - globalconfigurations
  - transportservers
  verbs:
  - list
  - watch
  - get
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: nginx-ingress
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
     #annotations:
       #prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
       #prometheus.io/port: "9113"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress
      containers:
      - image: nginx/nginx-ingress:1.6.3
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx-ingress
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
       #- name: prometheus
         #containerPort: 9113
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          runAsUser: 101 #nginx
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        args:
          - -nginx-configmaps=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-config
          - -default-server-tls-secret=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-server-secret
          - -enable-custom-resources=false
         #- -v=3 # Enables extensive logging. Useful for troubleshooting.
         #- -report-ingress-status
         #- -external-service=nginx-ingress
         #- -enable-leader-election
         #- -enable-prometheus-metrics
         #- -global-configuration=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-configuration

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "tcp"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
    protocol: TCP
    name: https
  selector:
    app: nginx-ingress
```

and that's the ingress resource :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: micro-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
    - host: kibana.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: kibana
              servicePort: 5601
```

Comment: have you add private hosted zone for "kibana.com" at the aws 53 route?

Comment: no i didn't, but should i add it ?

Comment: yes . you need to create private hosted zone "kibana.com" and add cname record "kibana.com" and fill the value with the aws nlb

Comment: i have already created one but when i access it it shows me : This domain has been suspended due to non-completion of an ICANN-mandated contact verification.

Comment: then you need to use custom domain that havent use by a company

Comment: Looks like you are sending your request to public kibana.com. I recommend for testing to change the /etc/hosts file on your machine. Add an entry kibana.com and point it to your Vnet-IP of your ingress service.

Comment: i'm sorry but how to can i check ingress vnet-ip ?

Comment: Run "kubectl get svc" and check the external IP of the service you want to reach. It should not be a public Ip (because you have the annotation set). Use this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is relevant, can't see your service definition

try using internal Loadbalancers like below, instead of boolean value, give ip address notation

`service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0`